# Predefined function in Mathematica

Tags: functions

How can I know the list of predefined functions ? Because often when I'm defining a function it already exist as c[n,k] gives $\binom{n}{k}$, and I also had problem with defining a function F. In general, is it possible to erase all functions ?

Comment: To find out if a function is built-in, search the documentation. For your example, search for [`Factorial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Factorial.html) in the documentation. Looking at the `See Also` sections shows [`Binomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Binomial.html) which is the built-in function for which you are looking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Erasing all functions would be catastrophic. You can find out if a symbol `f` has a definition by evaluating:

```
?f
```

All symbols with built-in definitions have names that start with capital letters or "$", so the common convention is to start your own symbols with lower case letters.

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpfull :-)

Answer (score 5):

It seems from the examples that it is the symbols the user has previously defined, either manually or through [`init.m`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/file/init.m.html) etc., that are at issue.

[`` ClearAll["Global`*"] ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ClearAll.html)
or 
[`` Clear["Global`*"] ``](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Clear.html) 
are in the docs of those commands under "Generalizations & Extensions".  These clear all symbols you have used (in the default global context).  Built-in functions are in the `` System` `` context and will not be affected by these.  Both commands clear any definitions/values, but `ClearAll` in addition clears other things such as [`Attributes`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Attributes.html). Some people use `Quit[]`, which quits the kernel (and effectively restarts it).

This will show you which symbols you have used have definitions:

```
Pick[Names["Global`*"], GeneralUtilities`HasDefinitionsQ /@ Names["Global`*"]]
```